# Tensorflow.py Protected division

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, eager-execution

I'm trying to implement a sort of protected division using `Tensorflow.where` but somehow it seems to be skipping the condition set on the `where` statement.

The main idea is, when dividing `x/y` , if `y == 0.` then the result of the division of be `x` instead of throwing and error.

My code is as follows:

```
def Pdivide(x,y):
    result = tf.where(y == 0., x, x/y) 
    return result
```

But somehow that condition is being skipped:

```
>>> a = tf.Variable([1.7, 0.2, 0., 1.1, 0.9, 0.3, 23., -1.])
>>> b = tf.Variable([0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1.])

>>>Pdivide(a,b)

>>>(inf, inf, nan, 1.1, 0.9, inf, 23, -1)
```

Intended output:

```
>>>(1.7, 0.2, 0., 1.1, 0.9, 0.3, 23, -1)
```

PS: Using `eager` execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the answer is pretty simple apparently.

For some reason the tensor elements cannot me compared with simple `==` but using `tf.equal(y, 0.)` solves the problem and produces the correct output.